# How to make forms stay in place when HTML display data is blank

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to make a form field stay in place whenever the HTML display data part is blank. The form field does stay in place whenever the display data part is filled in, but when it is blank, the form field moves upward and indents slightly to the right. I'm trying to code it in a way that when it is blank, the entire form field does not move upward, and does not indent slightly to the right.

My code looks like this:

```
          <h2 :title="option.ID">
            <image/>
            {{ option.Name }}
          </h2>

            <div class="row">
             <label class="bold">Option Name</label>
            </div>
              <div class="optio ">
                  <input
                    v-model="option.Name"
                    :disabled="isDisabled(option)"
                  >
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the minimum code needed to reproduce this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form probably moves up when the input is empty because of the rendering of option.Name in the `<h2>`. However, this would probably depend on the size of the image contained in it.

Could you try to add some dummy text next to `{{ option.Name }}` and see if the problem persists?

for instance:

```html
<h2 :title="option.ID">
  <image
    id="photo"
    alt="`photo picture`"
    title="option image"
    class="image" />
    {{ option.Name }} dummy text
</h2>
```

If the form doesn't move anymore, you can think of setting setting the height of the h2 in CSS, or force the rendering of some text when `option.Name` is undefined:

```html
<h2 :title="option.ID">
  <image
    id="photo"
    alt="`photo picture`"
    title="option image"
    class="image" />
    {{ option.Name || 'placeholder' }} dummy text
</h2>
```

Here, placeholder can be whatever you want, even a space

Comment: Thanks for this! They definitely both work. I tried out your second suggestion, but adding a space or leaving ' ' as blank does not work. I just added a different placeholder instead. Thank you!

Comment: But if you have any idea how to change the placeholder as a space instead of text, that'd be great!

Comment: I am glad it worked but sorry to hear that space doesn't work as a placeholder. I don't really see any other simple way to put an invisible placeholder but as this is a bit of a hacky technique anyway, I would recommend exploring the option of constraining the <h2>'s height in CSS